# Does $\pi_0$ preserve infinite products?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

The functor $\pi_0\colon \operatorname{sSets}\to \operatorname{Sets}$ has value on a simplicial set $X$ the coequalizer of the two boundary morphisms $d_0,d_1\colon X_1\to X_0$.

It is easy to see that $\pi_0$ preserves finite products.

> Does $\pi_0$ preserve infinite products?

Please let me add a follow-up question.

> Does $\pi_0$ preserve infinite products of Kan complexes? If this is not true, is there also a counterexample with simply connected spaces and countable products?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\pi_0$ does not preserve infinite products. Let $X$ be the nerve of the following category:
$$\bullet \leftarrow \bullet \rightarrow \bullet \leftarrow \bullet \rightarrow \bullet \leftarrow \bullet \rightarrow \cdots$$
$X$ is contractible but not a Kan complex. On the other hand, $X^{\mathbb{N}}$ is not contractible: the problem is that there is no uniform upper bound to the lengths of paths between points in $X$.

The problem goes away if you restrict to Kan complexes: indeed, if $K$ is a Kan complex, then the image of $K_1 \to K_0 \times K_0$ is an equivalence relation; in particular, two points in $K$ are in the same connected component if and only if there is a path of length 1 between them. Thus $\pi_0$ preserves all products of Kan complexes.

Comment: Nice, thanks! Do you say it is true that $\pi_0$ preserves infinite products of Kan complexes?

Comment: Isn't that what I said in the second paragraph?

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought this comment only concerns your example. Thank you!

Comment: Dear @Zhen Lin, sorry to bother you again but could you please write down some more details about your assertion on the Kan complexes? Suppose you have $\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}} X_i$ where all $X_i$ are Kan. Now you take two sequences $(x_0,x_1,\ldots)$ and $(x_0',x_1',\ldots)$. How to write doen a path between them? Thank you so much!

Comment: Do everything componentwise.